# Select ExtJS combobox item

Tags: c#, extjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to automate a web site that has ext.net controls in it using Selenium WebDriver and IE as browser. I can't select the combobox. I try to click the arrow to select element from the combobox. I can get the element but I can't click the element, I get ElementNotVisibleException {"Cannot click on element"}. I tried mouse over javascriptexecutor for the arrow image to be visible. It didn't work. I observed no mouse over action.

```
IWebElement cbArrow = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ext-gen93"));
string mouseOverscript = "var evt = document.createEventObject();" +
            "arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover', evt);";
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(mouseOverscript, cbArrow);
cbArrow.Click();
```

This is how it looks in firefox:

[image]

Comment: Is at mandatory for you to click the item from list of available ones? When I was working with ExtJs I handled combobox the next way: type text into field and then press 'Tab' key (by adding + "\t").

Comment: Thanks a lot, I actually tried to get the text element. It didn't work. The element can be found with firebug. But I get "NoSuchElementExeption". Could it be that this text is hidden? How can I make it visible?

Comment: can you share a link to your app?

Comment: If you mean the web site it is not reachable via internet I'm looking from the test environment. But I really don't get why I can't type in to the text of the combobox

Comment: I discover now I can't also get text elements from the page. This should be another problem to consider.

Comment: Just realized that you search a webelement using Id but I wouldn't do it. Id's in extJs are dynamic, so I would recommend to write a reliable xpath instead of using id's.

Comment: Unfortunately the same error occurs if I get try to get the element using xpath ElementNotFoundException...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50788/discussion-between-olyv-and-bilgestackoverflow)

Comment: may be your element is present inside an iframe. if that is the case, first you need to switch to that iframe and then you will be able to detect that element.